# Pandas how to increment value of rolling mean row by row in a specific range

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm left with NaN values when doing rolling operations. I want to fix this by applying adequately shorter rolling mean to fit a specific row. Here is the data example:

```
#get the rolling mean from last 7 days 
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(10, size=10), columns=['values'])
df['rolling7'] = df['values'].rolling(7).mean().round(1)
df.head(10)

   values  rolling7
0  7       NaN
1  6       NaN
2  3       NaN
3  4       NaN
4  0       NaN
5  9       NaN
6  0       4.1
7  1       3.3
8  3       2.9
9  9       3.7
```

I want to fill NaN with approximately shorter rolling means:

rolling(1) for row 0, rolling(2) for row 1, etc.

I understand why my code fails but I don't know how to fix that increment:

```
m = 0
for row in df.loc[0:6]:
        m = ++1
        df['rolling7'] = df['values'].rolling(m).mean().round(1)
df.head(10)

   values   rolling7
0  7        7.0
1  6        6.0
2  3        3.0
3  4        4.0
4  0        0.0
5  9        9.0
6  0        0.0
7  1        1.0
8  3        3.0
9  9        9.0
# and I don't know why it went through entire df even if I specified the rows
```

Answer (score 0):

`.rolling` takes an optional argument, `min_periods` after the window that will give you the behavior you're looking for. By setting it to `1`, it will provide the longest rolling average it can for each row:

```
In [14]: df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(10, size=10), columns=['values'])
    ...: df['rolling7'] = df['values'].rolling(7, 1).mean().round(1)
    ...: df.head(10)
    ...:
Out[14]:
   values  rolling7
0       9       9.0
1       0       4.5
2       1       3.3
3       7       4.2
4       9       5.2
5       7       5.5
6       1       4.9
7       3       4.0
8       5       4.7
9       3       5.0
```

As to why your code didn't work, there's 2 big issues. First, `m = ++1` is identical to `m = 1`, so it's never changing the value there. You probably intended `m += 1`. Second `df['rolling7'] = df['values'].rolling(m).mean().round(1)` operates on the entire column each time since you're assigning `rolling7` for the whole `df`.